# read int with scanf until new line

Tags: c, string, int, newline, scanf

I'm new to the c language and used java before, so I'm not so familiar with some things... I want to read an indefinite number of integer until there's a new line. I know, that new line is ⁄n and I already have a code, so the integer are read until you type in a letter, but it doesn't stop, if there's a new line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int i, numberOfNumbs=0,total=0,value, valsRead;
float average;

valsRead = scanf("%d",&value);

while(valsRead>0)
{
numberOfNumbs++;
total +=value;
printf("Read %d\n", value);
valsRead = scanf("%d",&value);
}

average=(float)total/(float)numberOfNumbs;
printf("You read %d values. Average = %f.",numberOfNumbs, average);

return (0);
}
```

The input should be something like this:
23 4 114 2 34 3224 3 2 ⁄n

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't `fgets()` just for files? I want to read it from the terminal... Sorry if I'm wrong :O

Comment: `stdin` *is* a file, or stream. It is the default console input, and is already "open".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf` is **not** line oriented *by design*. It is aimed for blank separated inputs, where blanks are any combinations of spaces, tabs, \r or \n.

If you want to use line oriented input, you should use `fgets` to get a line in a string and then strtok and sscanf to parse the string. Your code could become :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* maximum size of an input line : adapt to your needs */
#define SIZE 256

int main() {

    int i, numberOfNumbs=0,total=0,value, valsRead;
    float average;
    char line[SIZE], *val;
    char delims[] = " \t\r\n";

    if (fgets(line, SIZE, stdin) == NULL) { /* EOF */
        fprintf(stderr, "No input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (line[strlen(line) - 2] != '\n')  {/* line too long */
        fprintf(stderr, "Line too long\n");
        return 2;
    }
    val = strtok(line, delims);
    valsRead = sscanf(val, "%d",&value);

    while(valsRead>0)
    {
        numberOfNumbs++;
        total +=value;
        printf("Read %d\n", value);
        val = strtok(NULL, delims);
        valsRead = (val == NULL) ? 0 : sscanf(val, "%d",&value);
    }

    average=(float)total/(float)numberOfNumbs;
    printf("You read %d values. Average = %f.",numberOfNumbs, average);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: If I try to compile it, the compiler gives me a some errors :/

Comment: @bli77 : it should be better now - looks like I should have tried compile first ;-)

Comment: thank you, it works ^^ although I had to comment the if-loop for "line to long" out, because otherwise you always get the error, no matter what you type in

Comment: Note: `line[strlen(line) - 2]` could result in `line[-1]` or rarely `line[-2]` and cause problems.  Suggest `line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

if you want multiple values, then better use array,
also if want values until you enter new line `'\n'` is `scanf("%[^\n]", string);`

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to do for entry from the keyboard I would suggest reading in a string with

```
char string[100];

scanf("%s",string)
```

then you can work through the string looking for numbers with, for example, the command

```
sscanf(string,"%d",&integer)
```

the tricky thing here is that after you have got your first integer you need to find out where the first space is **after** your number.. say it is n characters after the start then you could repeat with

```
sscanf(string+n,"%d",&integer)
```

and test the value of sscanf to see if something was correctly read in.

This is not a full *answer*, but suggestion of a different strategy.

I do this sort of thing reading in from a file, but here you have to be careful because for a file end of line characters can either be ascii code 10, 13 or both 10 and 13 for unix, mac and msdos format files (and sorry I can't remember which is which.